# predict target for new data using nnet R

Tags: r, nnet

I am facing problems with predict function in nnet package R.

I have trained a nnet model in R with train data , but when I try to predict for new test samples I am getting more results than the number of test samples.

My train data contains 3673 rows and my test has 1225.
But when I predict for test data, I get 3673 target outputs. I have pasted my code below.

```
index<-1:nrow(wine_data)
set.seed(1)
train_ind <- sample(index,.75*nrow(wine_data))
train<-wine_data[train_ind,]
test<-wine_data[-train_ind,]

model.nnet<-nnet(formula=f,data=train,linout=FALSE,size=10)

predicted<-predict(model.nnet,data=test,type='class')
```

[image]

Above is screenshot of r console. Am I doing something wrong here. Kindly help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the last line of code you have

> data=train

So either put data=test, or new.data=test (depending on what the predict function for the nnet package says)

The predict function doesn't need the train data (most of the time), as it just remembers the model specification and can apply on new data with same features.
or use

```
predicted<-predict(model.nnet, test,type="class")
```

Comment: Hi thank you . Actually it was a typo. I have corrected my question above. I tried data=test , its still showing the same

Comment: What about
      predicted<-predict(model.nnet, test,type="class")

Thats how they have it in examples. It could be '/" case? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nnet/html/predict.nnet.html

Comment: Hi Jan thanks, you are right I tried replacing 'data=test' with 'test' , it worked. This my modified predict code predicted<-predict(model.nnet,test,type='class')

Comment: Great! Happy to help. Could you mark my answer please? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer as well. Could you accept it as answer please? Otherwise it will show as unanswered to everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem . When I replace **data=test** with **test** in predict function it works. This is my modified predict code.

predicted<-predict(model.nnet,test,type='class')